# Entity Framework Core, UD sql function throws System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am having a lot of trouble trying to run a SQL function from the `DbContext`, I have tried several suggestions with no luck.

I have a class library project, with Entity Framework Core (3.1.5). The project compiles and runs but when I try to run a unit test (before I deploy or integrate) every time I touch the function I get an error

> System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'

This is the SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLocalDate]()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @gd AS DATETIME =  getUTCdate()
     DECLARE @D AS datetimeoffset

     SET @D = CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @gd) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
     RETURN CONVERT(datetime, @D);
END
```

which is working in the database.

This is my database context:

```
public class VendorDbContext : DbContext
{
    public VendorDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    { }

    [DbFunction("GetLocalDate", "dbo")]
    public static DateTime GetLocalDate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => VendorDbContext.GetLocalDate());
    }
}
```

and this is the call in the class - `Context` is a local variable of the `VendorDbContext` type, and `Vendor` is an existing valid entity in the model:

```
var now = Context.Vendor.Where(v => v.CompanyId == 6)
                        .Select(v => VendorDbContext.GetLocalDate() ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Does not matter what I try, I always got the exception mentioned above.

Any ideas please?

Comment: When debugging I can reach the line in the function that throws the exception, so I am guessing is not properly mapped but I can tell why

Comment: So you're getting the exception when running a unit test? Are you mocking the DbContext or using an actual implementation? Also, do you get the exception when running the application normally?

Comment: Hi thanks so much for asking, the context is a EF empty context
using (VendorDbContext context = new VendorDbContext(options)) and i havent run it normally, until unit testing complete i am not supposed to integrate this.

Comment: now with that question i think is important to add that the unit testing is in memory database

Comment: yeah I'm guessing that's the crux of the matter. It seems that the in-memory provider is [rather limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database) functionality, so the `DbFunction` is likely just not executing as it would against a live database

Comment: Actually i think you are totally right, the function works totally fine when conected to a real DB

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. I found reason of this problem for my code. If `Entity Framework` didn't execute LINQ query and occured local evalution, your DbFunction will execute in C# side. Therefore `VendorDbContext.GetLocalDate()` called in C# side will throw `System.NotImplementedException`